# Iphone - Load image from camera roll to UIImageView without UIImagepicker

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, camera

Is it possible to load the last photo from camera roll to UIImageView without using a UIImagepicker?

I mean retrieve the path to the file or something like that.

Thankz :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using the new `AVFoundation` framework. You may want to take a look at the WWDC 2010 session videos discussing the framework and the related source code.

Comment: So i will not be able to make this work on iphone 3.1 devices, right?

Comment: You must verify this, but if I remember correctly AVFoundation is available starting from SDK 4.0