# Getting an image from the iPhone camera roll

Tags: iphone, camera, photo

I currently have a `UIImageView` and a `UIImage`. How do I allow the user to select one of their photos from the camera roll?

There are [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754137/iphone-load-image-from-camera-roll-to-uiimageview-without-uiimagepicker) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583909/how-to-get-photos-from-camera-roll), but I've had no luck. This might possibly be because I don't hook things up in the Interface Builder.

I would like something simple like `UIImage * image = [UIImage imageFromCameraRoll]`, but unfortunately, that's not possible (I don't think so, at least).

Comment: The class reference for `UIImagePickerViewController` is your best friend.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

It is help to you get image from `cameraroll` & `photolibrary`. using `UIImagePickerViewController`

if you take Picture

1. From camera (in both open As UINavigationcontroller).
2. From Gallery(for ipad open as UIpopovercontroller & for iphone open as nvigationcontroller).

**First set delegate**

```
@interface camera : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

**get image from Camera**

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];

            imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

            imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
            newMedia = YES;
            iscamera = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error to access Camera"
                                                            message:@""
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        }
```

**Get image from Gallery**

```
 if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *_picker=nil;
        if (popoverController) {
            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];

        }
        _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        _picker.delegate = self;        
        _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        _picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

        //[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                               //   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

           [self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];


        } else
        {
            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_picker];
            [popoverController setDelegate:self];
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame
                                               inView:self.view
                             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                             animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error access photo library"
                                                        message:@"your device non support photo library"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

**Both Result you get in Delegate Method**

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   // write your code here ........
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIImagePickerController`, see the Apple docs.

Select the source type:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType
```

From on on these:

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
```